# Equivalent to ul li in react styling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to make the `padding` on my `<li>` element equal 0 without using `styles=newListStyle`. I would like to use the the equivalent of the same syntax in css of `ul li`, to make my `li` element have no padding. Current code:

```
listOne: {
  width: '50%',
  float: 'left',
  fontSize: '30px',
  color: theme.colour.lightGrey,
  marginTop: '0',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontStretch: 'normal',
  textAlign: 'left'
},
```

Comment: add a class?...

Comment: I said I dont want to do that if possible. I want to select the li element from within `listOne`

Comment: Inline styles apply to a single element (although some rules cascade). You need to add another set of inline styles to the `li` elements too.

Comment: you can't do it without adding inline styles to every item in that case, why are you trying to avoid it out of curiosity?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use CSS modules for this, and import them into your react component like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './styles.css';

class Thing extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul className={styles.list}>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Then, in your `styles.css` file, you can do something like this:

```
ul.list {
  /* styles */
}

ul.list li {
  /* styles */
}
```

If you use inline styles like you did above, then you'll have no choice but to style each element separately, and you'll eliminate the possibility of using "cascading" in css.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that he's asking how he can do it using inline styles...

Comment: He didn't explicitly mention that.

Comment: > the equivalent of the same syntax in css

Answer (score 0):

There's no concept of selectors with inline styles. Styles can only be applied to a single element.

```
let listStyles = { ... };
let itemStyles = { padding: 0 };

<ul styles={listStyles}>
  <li styles={itemStyles} />
</ul>
```

There are some rules which will be inherited by children, such as color and font, but rules like padding must be specified explicitly.